# simple mysqli join query not working

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like this:

**subject_descriptors**
descriptor_id, subject_id, grades, descriptor

which has data rows like this:

```
1, 5, p2, some text
2, 5, p3, some more text
```

and

**subject_list**
subject_id, subject

which has rows of data like this

```
5, science
6, french
```

so as you can see a subject can have different grades/text

I want to create a query which gives me:

subject, grades, descriptor

something like:

```
science, p2, some text
science, p3, some more text
```

I have tried unsuccessfully various joins like this:

```
SELECT subject_list.subject, subject_descriptors.grades 
FROM subject_list, subject_descriptors 
WHERE subject_list.subject_id = subject_descriptors.subject_id
```

which I know is wrong but I can't get my head around it. Any help please?

Comment: I think something like `select sd.descriptor, sd.grades, s.subject from subject_descriptors as sd join subject_list as s on sd.subject_id = s.subjectid` would do it? You tagged this with `mysqli` and `PHP` though was there an issue with that?

Comment: well I suppose not perhaps - I just wondered if I what I was doing was some incorrect use of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT sl.subject, sd.grades, sd.descriptor 
FROM subject_descriptors sd
INNER JOIN subject_list sl ON sd.subject_id = sl.subject_id
```